# What happened with the default autocompletion suggestions for the UITextView?

Tags: autocomplete, uitextview

I used to enable set Correction = YES in the interface builder to get the live autocompletion suggestions. Now when I do that, the text gets autocompleted without letting me choose from any previous suggestion. In fact, it forces me to write words I don't want to write. Can somebody tell me what happened? How do I get the old suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the UITextView TextViewDidChange I created a thread that changed the cursor position. This, off course happens after the text view changes. The change of the cursor position triggers the autocomplete without letting me even see that there had been a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the code had resignFirstResponder then becomeFirstResponder right after for the UITextView.  I dunno why that was there, but removing it fixed the problem.